# How can I get the results from an AlertDialog?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-alertdialog

I am using an AlertDialog.Builder to display a dialog to prompt the user to enter a password, I then want to save that password in a preference, however I can't figure out how to get the result from the alert dialog's input method.

Here is essentially what I would like to be able to do:

```
    String result;
    AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    b.setTitle("Please enter a password");
    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    b.setView(input);
    b.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
        {
           //I get a compile error here, it wants result to be final.
           result = input.getText().toString();
        }
    });
    b.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", null);
    b.create().show();
```

However, I am open to doing something such as `showDialog(int);` then using the `onCreateDialog(int)` method and somehow setting the result and receiving it in some other method, but I have no idea how to go about the last part.

Comment: See also [Callback on AlertDialog](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/52351/callback-on-alertdialog)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private String result;

    void showDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        b.setTitle("Please enter a password");
        final EditText input = new EditText(this);
        b.setView(input);
        b.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                result = input.getText().toString();
            }
        });
        b.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", null);
        b.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Simplified example:

```
public interface TextListener {
    void onPositiveResult(CharSequence text);
}

public static AlertDialog getTextDialog(Context ctx,
        final TextListener listener) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(ctx).inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
    final TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
    builder.setView(view);
    //
    builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            listener.onPositiveResult(tv.getText());
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null);
    return builder.create();
}
```

-- EDIT --
Or you try this code:

```
 public class Main extends Activity {
    private Button btn;
    private String result;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog(0);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case 0:
            final EditText input = new EditText(this);

            return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setTitle("Please enter a password")
            .setView(input)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), input.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Cancel clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }).create();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand what's going on here, or how I would use this to achieve what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: evilone is suggesting you use the Observer pattern and create your own listener (TextListener).  Your Activity that is housing this AlertDialog can then implement TextListener which will call onPositiveResult(CharSequence) outside of the AlertDialog, and it will pass in the result that you are looking for based on your question.  You can then act on your result as you wish.

Answer (score 3):

You can follow the [Dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) tutorial in developer.android.com.

First create dialog class:

[Adding a list](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AddingAList)

Then add listener to this class to pass result to the activity.

[Passing Events Back to the Dialog's Host](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#PassingEvents)

Answer (score 2):

Weak but speedy solution:

Declare an Activity level method:

```
TextView lblDiaDestination;

public void dialogReturn(String msg){
   lblDiaDestination.setText(msg);
}
```

and call it from positive button click listner:

```
alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        dialogReturn(   input.getText().toString().trim()   );
    });
```

You can change lblDiaDestination value just before alert.show():

```
lblDiaDestination = myTextView;
alert.show():
```

Answer (score 1):

Variable result , make it a member variable , instead of local variable. By making "result" as member variable it is accessible in the entire activity.(parent class which extends activity)

Comment: +1 for right answer. I chose @Femi's because it was more robust. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This quite long. I hope my contribution could be useful for the the new comers.
I think the key to answer the question is declaring the variable **result** as member of the activity (let's call it **YourActivity**). Then from inside the "onClick" method, use **YourActivity.this.result** to access this variable.

I edit @finiteloop codes as below:

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {
    private String result;
    // other activity stuff

    void showDialog(){
        AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        b.setTitle("Please enter a password");
        final EditText input = new EditText(this);
        b.setView(input);
        b.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {        
               YourActivity.this.result = input.getText().toString();
            }
        });
        b.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", null);
        b.create().show();
    }
}
```