# how do you add an item in a list if a user presses yes button in an alert dialog box and don't add it if he presses no

Tags: java, android, dialog, android-alertdialog

I am making an app in which if a user selects a
submenu item I pop up an Alert dialog which asks his confirmation
whether he wishes to save that item in his list and saves it if he
presses yes and doesn't add it if he presses no.

Comment: Have a look at this question - it describes exactly what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953644/how-can-i-get-the-results-from-an-alertdialog

Comment: Please show us the code you have written so far. We'll be able to better help you if you can show us exactly the point at which you are having difficulties.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to show alert:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure to do this?").setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    doSomeThing();
                                            dialog.cancel();
                }
            }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You add the element you get from the dialog to the ArrayList you use to feed your `Adapter` then feed the `cursor = new yourAdapter(YourClass.this.getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, dataList);`

Call `cursor.notifyDataSetChanged();` which tells the list to repopulate with the new data;

Comment: This is WAY overcomplicated for what he needs.  All that's required is to get the result from an AlertDialog